# What does the message mean and how do i fix my code?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, scientific-computing

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds yo your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''students'('subject_id')  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE 
>   FOREIGN KEY (subje' at line 8

```
CREATE TABLE Entries
 (
entry_id int NOT NULL,
subject_id int NOT NULL,
student_id int NOT NULL,
exam_date int,
PRIMARY KEY (subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES 'students'('student_id')
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE 
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES 'subjects'('subject_id')
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the single quotes arround column and table names:

```
CREATE TABLE Entries
 (
entry_id int NOT NULL,
subject_id int NOT NULL,
student_id int NOT NULL,
exam_date int,
PRIMARY KEY (subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE 
)
```

And also there is no Need to add the key twice